# Refazer perguntas do SOen

Tags: debate

Eu utilizo tanto o SOpt quanto o SOen, mas dou preferencia ao SOpt devido a maior facilidade de entendimento já que não sou fluente e me deparei com o seguinte pensamento onde no SOen existe muitas perguntas de conhecimento "básico" ( muito bem formuladas e respondidas que fique bem claro ) e  que aqui no SOpt vejo com menos frequência perguntas assim, seria uma boa idéia refazer essas mesmas perguntas e respostas traduzidas para aumentar o conteúdo da comunidade e ajudar aqueles que não possuem conhecimento do idioma (evitando assim que algumas pessoas fazem por exemplo de jogar tudo no google tradutor gerando mais confusão)

Comment: @Stormwind tinha procurado mas n tava achando, obrigado

Comment: vou votar fechar a pergunta então

Comment: Vinicius só pra constar, ambas comunidades são diferentes, só carregam o mesmo nome, mas não tem relação alguma em "nível comunidade", logo não tem problema nenhum, note que existe SOen (inglês), SOpt (português), SOru (russo), SOes (espanhol) e SOja (japonês)

Comment: Não sei se a resposta linkada basta, porque ela é do tempo do beta privado do site ainda. Mas em resumo sim, pode postar perguntas que já existam no SOen, e até respondê-las você mesmo se quiser. Porém, evite postar muitas perguntas assim uma atrás da outra, pois isso pode ser mal-visto pela comunidade.

Comment: Sim , eu entendi, pelo que entendo pode ser visto como se eu tivesse a intenção de ganhar pontos, mas na vdd eu tinha pensando nisso pq andei vendo muitos usuários citando nas perguntas como "sou novo na area" e muitas coisas que eles estavam errando era coisa simples que para quem tem um pouco de experiencia poderia responder

Comment: É bem-vindo, desde que faça com qualidade.